# Afterlogic Webmail Lite custom theme / skin

Tags: css, less, themes, skin, webmail

I would like to make a custom dark theme for a web client.

I tried everything but no matter what I changed I cannot get any changes to take effect. I found out this page in the documentation but I cannot get it to work:
https://afterlogic.com/docs/webmail-lite-8/developers-guide/creating-new-skin

Does anyone have some experience with this webmail client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended option for creating a new skin is to clone and rename one of the existing skins, and upon making changes to it, run `gulp styles --themes YOUR_THEME_NAME` command. Once this operation is performed, check `static/styles/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME` and see if you get your changes reflected there. If the changes are in place, then it's probably browser cache causing it, try clearing it and see if that helps.

In fact, it's not required to deal with `.less` files, you can simply create a copy of an existing theme under `static/styles/themes` directory - but in either case, you need to make sure the new theme is listed in `ThemeList` section of `data/settings/modules/CoreWebclient.config.json` configuration file.